# Python lists and function, finding the max/min months of rainfall

Tags: python, list

My program is supposed to take the rainfall amounts for each month and calculate the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest(max) and lowest(min) rainfall amounts.

Everything works as planned, except for the highest and lowest month outputs. I need for this to display the name of the months with the highest and lowest rainfall amounts. I can get the correct values to display, just not the name of the month.

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
          "May", "June", "July", "August",
          "September", "October", "November", "December"]
values = []
year = []

for i in months :
    values.append(float(input("Enter total rain for " + i + ": ")))
print()



def total():
    print("The total rainfall for the year is %.2f" % sum(values))
total()

def average():
    print("The average monthly rainfall is %.2f" % float(sum(values)/ 12))
average()

def highest():
    print("The highest monthly rainfall is", max(values))
highest()

def lowest():
    print("The lowest monthly rainfall is", min(values))
lowest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the index of the min/max values and then use that index to find the month. Using a [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is the more pythonic way to do it, but here is another beginner's approach

```
def highest():
    print("The highest rainfall month is:",months[values.index(max(values))] )
    print("The highest monthly rainfall is", max(values))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning Python so everything is a beginner's approach for me. I appreciate the help very much!

Comment: Just curious, is there another way to do this without the 'values.index' portion of the code?  My textbook just barely explains this, so I don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the `values` with the `months` and get the `min` or `max` of that, being a tuple of `(value, month)`. Make sure to put the value first, so it is used for sorting.

```
>>> months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
...           "May", "June", "July", "August",
...           "September", "October", "November", "December"]
>>> values = [47, 2, 28, 9, 4, 64, 28, 94, 1, 9, 4, 23]  # or whatever
>>> val, month = min(zip(values, months))
>>> print("The lowest rainfall was %r in %s" % (val, month))
The lowest rainfall was 1 in September
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` and `min` return the largest or smallest value in a list, respectively. You can use `index` to get the index of that value, and then use the index to get the month's name. E.g.:

```
def highest():
    max_value = max(values)
    ind = values.index(max_value)
    month_name = months[ind]
    print("The highest monthly rainfall is %d, occurring on %s" % \
    (max_value, month_name))
```

Comment: Just curious, is there another way to do this without the 'values.index' portion of the code? My textbook just barely explains this, so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @AndrewN. Using `zip` is a neat way around ti - see tobias_k's answer

Comment: @Mureinik-- Yes, it looks like an effective way, but we have not learned anything about using zip either. But thanks for replying so quickly!